# Python: KeyError: u'key' when analyzing multiple netCDF files

Tags: python, netcdf, keyerror

I'm relatively new to Python and am trying to analyze an entire folder of netCDF files. When I try to run my code I get the key error: `u'satcode'`. Here is my code:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import glob
import numpy as np

filenames = []
for name in glob.glob("/Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/*"):
  print name
  filenames.append(name)
# below reads multiple files (file_list)
f = nc.MFDataset(filenames)
```

I know the error is with `f = nc.MFDataset(filenames)`, but I don't know why.
My traceback says:

> runfile('/Users/my_name/.spyder/West_Coast_Model.py', wdir='/Users/my_name/.spyder')
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGG.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.01.0000.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00 (5).nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.0300.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.0600.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.0900.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.1200.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.1500.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.1800.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.07.99.2100.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   /Users/my_name/Desktop/ISCCP/ISCCP-Basic.HGH.v01r00.GLOBAL.1983.08.99.0000.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/my_name/.spyder/West_Coast_Model.py', wdir='/Users/my_name/.spyder')
>
> File "/Users/my_name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "/Users/my_name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
>       builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
>
> File "/Users/my_name/.spyder/West_Coast_Model.py", line 20, in 
>       f = MFDataset(filenames)
>
> File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5888, in >netCDF4._netCDF4.MFDataset.**init**
>
> KeyError: u'satcode'

Comment: Please have a minimal and complete example of your code, as well as the full text of your traceback. Without these, we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: I think you can just pass the wildcard string to MFDataset instead of using glob manually

Comment: Can you add the full traceback? I don't see anything wrong in the code that you posted.

Comment: I added the traceback, so I hope you can find what doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. The 0th term in the files was corrupted, so I redownloaded it and converted it into netCDF4_CLASSIC and it worked.